# Como é feito o cálculo de matemática do módulo (%) em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, matemática

Estou a tentar utilizar "engenharia reversa" para entender qual é o cálculo feito pelo módulo (`%`), mas não estou a conseguir perceber e queria entender e esclarecer-me, para deixar claro esta parte, antes de avançar e começar a fazer exercícios com ele.

Então eu vi este exemplo:

> > If we do `23 % 10,` we divide 23 by 10 which equals 2 with 3 left over. So `23 % 10` evaluates to `3`.
>
> More examples:
> `17 % 5` evaluates to `2`
> `13 % 7` evaluates to `6`

Neste primeiro exemplo ele diz que dividimos `23 / 10` que é igual a `2` mas na verdade se fizéssemos esse calculo daria `2,3`. Então eu pensei, talvez o que isto quer dizer é:

> `23 % 10` igual a 2 com 3 de fora, deve significar `23 / 3` igual a `2,3`, então esta seria a razão do igual a `2` e `3` de fora?!

Mas depois quando apliquei esta teoria nos exemplos seguintes, esta teoria não se aplicou... Também pensei que pudesse ser a divisão do número `23` por 2 que arredondado seria 10 10 deixando os 3 de fora, mas essa teoria também não teria lógica porque senão seria `23 % 2` em vez de `23 % 10`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A conta é feita em cima de valores inteiros, exatamente como é na matemática. O algoritmo seria mais ou menos isto:

```js
let x = 23;
let y = 10;
let temp = Math.trunc(x / y); //pega a parte inteira, então o 2,3 vira 2
let modulo = x - temp * y; //pega o dividendo menos o maior valor inteiro divisível
console.log(modulo);
console.log((17 - Math.trunc(17 / 5) * 5));
console.log((13 - Math.trunc(13 / 7) * 7));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/Mod.js).

Comment: Aviso: essa função de truncamento faz parte do ES6 e não está disponível em `Math` em qualquer browser.

Comment: É, bom aviso. nesse caso foi mais para demonstrar o funcionamento, ninguém vai fazer essa fórmula se tem o operador pronto.

Answer (score 11):

O conceito de ["módulo"](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aritm%C3%A9tica_modular) é semelhante ao de ["resto da divisão [inteira]"](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resto_da_divis%C3%A3o_inteira):

```
Dividendo ou numerador: 23
Divisor ou denominador: 10
Quociente: 2
Resto: 3
```

Não é exatamente o mesmo conceito (segundo a Wikipedia, as linguagens de programação mais comuns - inclusive JavaScript - implementam o resto da divisão no seu operador `%`, e não o módulo), mas é próximo o bastante, principalmente quando todos os números envolvidos são inteiros e positivos (como nos seus exemplos). Entretanto, não é sempre o caso:

```js
// Em JavaScript, o dividendo determina o sinal do resto
log(23 % 10);   // 3
log(-23 % 10);  // -3
log(23 % -10);  // 3
log(-23 % -10); // -3

// Se o dividendo não for inteiro, o resto também não é inteiro
log(23.5 % 10); // 3.5

// Se o divisor não for inteiro, não importa, o quociente é que sempre tem de ser inteiro
log(23 % 10.5);   // 2
log(23.5 % 10.5); // 2.5

function log(x) { document.body.innerHTML += "<p>" + x + "</p>"; }
```

Outras linguagens podem seguir convenções diferentes ou possuir restrições diferentes quanto ao tipo dos operandos (não sei dizer se isso é padronizado ou não). Sobre como o cálculo é feito, creio que a [resposta do Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/93095/215) já explica muito bem (sendo consistente com o operador `%` em todos os casos citados acima).

Sobre o módulo em si, caso tenha curiosidade, trata-se de uma relação de equivalência entre vários valores segundo um critério bem definido. Não faz sentido perguntar "qual o valor de X módulo Y?", na verdade X é equivalente a infinitos números módulo Y:

```
23 ≡ 3 ≡ 13 ≡ -7 ≡ -17 ≡ ... (mod 10)
```

Apenas um deles - o `3` - satisfaz à relação `0 <= 3 < 10`, de modo que é comumente considerado o valor "canônico", mas isso só faz sentido (e é útil) quando o módulo (`10`) é positivo e inteiro.

Answer (score 4):

### Só para complementar

Ambas as respostas do Maniero e do mgibsonbr são bastantes boas e completas, obrigado pelo esclarecimento e informações adicionais que me instruíram mais =) . Enquanto pesquisava mais sobre este assunto, encontrei aqui um [exemplo no SO em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13710545/3624981) sobre este mesmo assunto, que achei que seria de valor adicionar aqui à 'documentação'.

Calculando o seguinte exemplo: `16 % 6 = 4`

```
16 / 6 = 2
```

Depois multiplica-se o quociente (resultado da divisão) por `6` (que é o divisor):

```
2 * 6 = 12
```

E por fim subtrai-se o dividendo:

```
16 - 12 = 4
```

O resultado dá `4`. O número 4 é o resto, que é o mesmo resultado da divisão do modulo que iremos obter, ao fazer `16 % 6 = 4`.