# Corrigir retorno de módulo incorreto

Tags: python, python-3.x, matemática

Matematicamente falando por que acontece e como corrigir o seguinte "erro" no python:

```
>>>10.53 % 1
0.5299999999999994
```

Eu gostaria de entender como o `python` trabalha para obter esse valor, por que isso ocorre.

De fato a [possível duplicada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44715/como-arredondar-um-float-em-python) formata a saída através do comando `print`.

Mas eu gostaria de trabalhar sem o `print`...

[Veja](https://ideone.com/fmMlvy)

Comment: Tenta `a = 10.53 % 1` e `print("%.2f" % a)` **:)**

Comment: É um erro usar a tag [erro]. :)

Comment: Sobre o porquê desse erro, o assunto é discorrido nessa questão: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/64969

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado 2 fantásticas respostas, 1 mais didática outra mais técnica, entretanto talvez para eu obter a resposta que eu esperava, a pergunta deveria ter sido: "Como é realizado o cálculo de módulo" que por sinal : >>>> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/93092/como-%C3%A9-feito-o-c%C3%A1lculo-de-matem%C3%A1tica-do-m%C3%B3dulo-em-javascript  Agora fazendo um mistão estou começando a entender...  Vlw a dica;)

Comment: @MagicHat a intenção era só mostrar o porque da representação dar esses erros. De fato, para entender melhor o módulo é muito mais interessante essa questão que você linkou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O 'problema' não só em python, acontece em muitas outras linguagens, algumas não 'demonstram' porque tratam logo internamente o resultado. Isto tem sido assunto desde os primeiros tempos da computação, e tem a ver com uma aproximação binária dos números em vez de decimal.

[SABER MAIS (python)](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

[SABER MAIS (geral PT)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/44718/5749)

[SABER MAIS (geral EN)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/588014/3162303)

Para conseguires realizar operações matemáticas com precisão e não apenas formatar o output podes usar o modulo [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/decimal.html)

```
from decimal import Decimal

value = Decimal('10.53') % 1
print(value) # 0.53
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://ideone.com/5xNXpp)

Answer (score 2):

Isso acontece porque alguns números não podem ser representados exatamente na notação de ponto flutuante.

O que você pode fazer nesse caso é aproximar o número pra um número determinado de casas decimais quando for mostrar ao usuário:

```
print('%0.2f' % (10.53 % 1))
```

O maior problema é se você precisa fazer várias operações com pontos flutuantes em sequência. Nesse caso o erro pode aumentar cada vez mais. Dependendo do caso, você pode trabalhar com números inteiros, multiplicando os valores por 100 por exemplo, e quando for mostrar o resultado final, dividir por 100 de novo e arredondar. Fazendo isso o erro vai ser minimzado.

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção, por hora não tenho como avaliar, se vai servir para meu caso, creio que não, pois a operação tá no meio do código, no meio de uma função recursiva, no meio de um loop... heheh  Mas na real, meu problema não é arredondar, mas saber como as linguagens de programação fazem para obter esses resultado...