# Uma questão simples usando % em JS

Tags: javascript, matemática

Estou aprendendo JavaScript e me deparei com uma questão que foi resolvida por outro, mas usado um `%` (cifrão) no código. Eu ainda sou muito leigo para entender, mas alguém poderia me explicar a real utilidade desse simbolo matemático?

Acho que a pergunta seria, como eu interpreto essa parte matemática quando aparece o cifrão? Diria que o resto é `i` de `2%`? Será o correto?

```
function pares (x, y){
    var i, j;
    i = x;
    j = y;

    for (i = x; i <= j; i++){
        *resto = i % 2;*
        if (resto === 0) {
            console.log('Numero par: ' + Math.floor(i))
        }
    }
}
console.log(pares(32, 321))
```

Comment: Esse símbolo % é cifrão?

Comment: Ta mais para uma interrogação kkk. Agora falando a sério, esse símbolo é de porcentagem Alberty, porém ele não tem nada a ver com o símbolo `%` usado na matemática.

Comment: Boa, kkk... Ser leio tem sua vantagens.. Obrigado amigo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O nome do símbolo **%** é *porcentagem* ou *percentagem*. Ele representa o *módulo* ou *mod* entre dois números INTEIROS.

Utilizamos este símbolo para saber qual é o resto da divisão entre dois valores. Caso ele seja **0**, ou seja, **não restar nada**, significa que ele é divisível, caso contrário ele não é.

**Exemplo:**

`10 % 2` resulta em `0`, logo, `10` é divisível por `2`. (PAR)

`5 % 2` resulta em `1`, logo, `5` NÃO é divisível por `2`. (IMPAR)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**No exemplo da imagem ficaria assim:**

`12 % 4` isso daria `0` (RESTO)

`12 / 4` isso daria `3` (QUOCIENTE)

Por isso que na função ele verifica se o resto é igual a zero.

Bons estudos!

Answer (score 5):

Este costuma ser chamada de operador de módulo, mas na verdade ele acha o resto de uma divisão inteira, as pessoas confundem isso porque é muito parecido ([pode ver mais detalhes disso na resposta do mgibsonbr](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/93092/101)). Ele faz uma divisão mas em vez de resultar no valor dela ele resulta no resto que daria nesse divisão.

No *link* acima tem uma fórmula que se aproxima de como o resto deve ser calculado na mão, ele não é preciso, é só para dar uma ideia).

> a real utilidade desse simbolo matemático?

Esqueça o símbolo, nem o trate como se fosse uma porcentagem (menos ainda cifrão que seria o $). Trate ele apenas como operador de resto. No nosso contexto este não é um símbolo matemático real, já que na matemática isto deveria resultar em um cálculo percentual. È esquisito, mas foi o que deu para fazer. A porcentagem é fácil obter, o resto nem tanto por isso criaram um operador e usaram este símbolo.

> como eu interpreto essa parte matemática quando aparece o cifrão?

No exemplo como você quer o **resto de uma divisão** por 2 só há dois resultados possíveis, 0 ou 1, portanto:

- se um número for par o resto é 0
- se for ímpar ele é 1.

Todo número divisível de forma inteira resultará em 0. Isto também, é usado para descobrir quais são os primos ou outras fórmulas.

> Diria que o resto é i de 2%? Será o correto?

Você pode dizer: "**o resto de i dividido por 2**"

Eu fiz o código de forma  mais simplificada:

```js
function pares(x, y) {
    for (let i = x; i <= y; i++) if (i % 2 === 0) console.log('Numero par: ' + i);
}
pares(32, 321);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/Rest.js).

Note que eu simplifiquei seu código e resolvi algumas coisas que potencialmente poderiam gerar problemas e m código mais complexo, por isso preste bastante atenção nele, em todos os caracteres.

E saiba que este caso poderia ser mais simplificado e performático:

```js
function pares(x, y) {
    for (let i = x; i <= y; i += 2) console.log('Numero par: ' + i);
}
pares(32, 321);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/Rest2.js).

Comment: Agradeço o tempo, agors entendo o significado e irei copiar eu código para estudar e melhorar o meu, agradeço o tempo e toda a explicação... Muito obrigado.